# Android Keyboard Language

Tags: android, locate

I am using the LG Optimus P500 android device
I want to set the my language as norwegian but it is not display in Language and settings -> Locate Option
My device has Android 2.2 version

In Android 2.2 version the norwegian language support but the norwegian language is not display in Locate option

What i have to do for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Norwegian is not supported in Android 2.2. It's supported in Android 2.3 as you can see here:

Android 2.2 Locale support: http://d.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html#locs

Android 2.3 Locale support: http://d.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html#locs

Comment: How can we set Locate at runtime

Comment: I don't know in a LG, but in "default" Android: Settings -> Language & Keyboard -> Select Language